# Xcode shortcut for last editing position

Tags: xcode, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Like `Ctl + Q` in eclipse, what is the Xcode shortcut key for moving cursor to the last editing position of a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far I know there is not exactly the shortcut for last edited location. But you can go forward and back of the navigated locations.

Go forward: ctrl+command+right arrow

Go back: ctrl+command+left arrow

You may find the keyboard shortcut for xcode by going Xcode->Preferences->Key Bindings.

Comment: how on earth smart company like Apple forgot such an important shortcut! i really miss it. :(

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `cmd + z` then `cmd + shit + z`.

Why Xcode 10 STILL doesn't support command of back to last edit location?